# Spring Assistant plugin not found in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I want to create a Spring Boot project from scratch in IntelliJ IDE. As there is also a way to use Spring Initializr to create a Spring Boot project and then download the zip and import to IDE.

As it is bit time consuming process to do that every-time, so I checked over the internet to see if there exists a plugin for the same which automatically loads Spring Initializr onto IntelliJ and found there is one named with Spring Assistant.

But this plugin is not visible in IntelliJ Plugins Marketplace. So I went over to JetBrains site for this plugin and landed on this page. This url is the download link for this plugin and is available for all versions. I am using the Community version.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant/versions

After downloading and importing the plugin, Spring Assistant option was visible under the `File -> New Project` section. But after specifying the project details, the dependency screen was not loading up (shown in last image) and I also get errors at the bottom of my IDE which says the plugin doesn't belongs to JetBrains. After this I also seem to feel IntelliJ IDE getting hanged. I have attached images for better understanding.

As anyone else faced a similar problem, because if this doesn't work then the only option is to go to Initializr every time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Seems plugin isn't supported in the latest versions.

Comment: The version that I use is IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4 (Community Edition). If this plugin is not supported, is there an alternate one that they have proposed.

Comment: Downgade your intellij version or just create the project in https://start.spring.io/ and import int in your workspace

Comment: That is one solution which I have already used but my main focus was how to do same within IDE. Is there a new plugin which is provided instead of spring assistant because making the plug-in incompatible for higher version doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: The provided plugin its different from the plugin you pointed out, the provided with the utilimate version it's made by jetbrains. You are using an older version of Intellij trying to use a plugin abandoded  3 years ago. You cannot pretend that a 3 years old plugin works with an IDE that came out the last year. JetBrains, changes a lot of things on each realease, so its normal that some plugins may not work, properly or work at all. By the way i posted a fork of the original plugin. Should work with your version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

https://github.com/eltonsandre/intellij-spring-assistant

Its a fork of the original plugin, according to the comments [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant/reviews), seems to work with 2020.3.1, 2021.1(those are the tested versions, check in the comment section).

Here the [changelog](https://github.com/eltonsandre/intellij-spring-assistant/blob/19010a17a8cf5d59515b2bd8eccb215cb87dd6ba/CHANGELOG.md) of the forked plugin

Comment: This link isn't working anymore

Comment: Using just https://github.com/eltonsandre/intellij-spring-assistant/  the link works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the plugin that served part of the idea/spring community, stopped maintaining. I took the liberty of creating a fork, we fixed bugs and added new features.

the same can be found directly in the search for Intellij or in the marketplace.

[Spring Boot Helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-initializr-and-assistant)

Comment: Unfortunately this is available as 30 day trial or buy out option. Is there any source where I can get it permanently?